# Odd behavior when Command Buttons are present. Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

Create a macro-enabled document that has a working macro first, but then stops working with the insertion of a Button. Instructions below.

The code:

```
Sub UpdateOptions()
  Dim bProtected As Boolean
  'Unprotect the file
  If ActiveDocument.ProtectionType <> wdNoProtection Then
    bProtected = True
    ActiveDocument.Unprotect Password:=""
  End If

  Select Case ActiveDocument.FormFields("Bookmark0").Result
    Case "Bookmark1"
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Bookmark1").Select
        SendKeys "%{down}"  'Displays choices in drop-down field
    Case "Bookmark2"
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Bookmark2").Select
        SendKeys "%{down}"  'Displays choices in drop-down field
    Case "Bookmark3"
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Bookmark3").Select
        SendKeys "%{down}"  'Displays choices in drop-down field
  End Select
  If bProtected = True Then
    ActiveDocument.Protect _
        Type:=wdAllowOnlyFormFields, _
        NoReset:=True, _
        Password:=""
  End If
End Sub
```

---

**Steps to set up the Word document:**

- Type into the document: Bookmark0
- Insert a Legacy Drop down Form Field

  - List entries: Bookmark1, Bookmark2, Bookmark3
  - Name: Bookmark0
  - Run Macro on Exit: UpdateOptions (code above)
- After the drop-down, type: Enter, Enter (insert two paragraphs)
- Type: Bookmark1
- Insert a second Legacy Drop down Form Field

  - List: 1, 2, 3.
  - Name: Bookmark1
- After the drop-down, type: Enter, Enter (insert two paragraphs)
- Type: Bookmark 2
- Insert a third Legacy Drop down Form Field

  - List: 1, 2, 3.
  - Name: Bookmark2
- After the drop-down, type: Enter, Enter (insert two paragraphs)
- Type: Bookmark3
- Insert a fourth Legacy Drop down Form Field

  - List: 1, 2, 3.
  - Name: Bookmark3

Your document should look like this at this point:

> Bookmark0[dropdown]
>
> Bookmark1[dropdown]
>
> Bookmark2[dropdown]
>
> Bookmark3[dropdown]

- Save the document as a Macro Enabled document (docm).
- Protect the document for filling in as a form

**Testing:**

- Change the first drowpdown options only from the available listed options (Bookmark1, Bookmark2, Bookmark3)
- Every time you change your selection you will be directed to the corresponding Bookmark Dropdown Form Field.
- Should be working as expected.

---

**Button conflict**

- Unlock document
- Insert a Button at the end of the document below Bookmark3 [Button]

Your document should look like the same as above but with a button now:

> Bookmark0[dropdown]
>
> Bookmark1[dropdown]
>
> Bookmark2[dropdown]
>
> Bookmark3[dropdown]
>
> [Button]

- Protect the document for filling in as a form

**Testing Button conflict:**

- Change Bookmak0 selection from (Bookmark1, Bookmark2, Bookmark3)
- Every time you change your selection you will NOT be directed to the corresponding Bookmark Dropdown Form Field.
- Every time you change your selection you will be directed to a field after the intended corresponding Bookmark Dropdown Form Field.
- Macro is not working as expected with the presence of a Button.
- Unprotect the document, delete the button, re-protect document, it will be working fine again.

---

I posted this questions on the links below too (Files available for download there.:
http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?65092-Odd-behavior-when-Command-Buttons-are-present

http://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/42422-odd-behavior-when-command-buttons-present.html

eileenslounge.com/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=32411

Comment: I can repro the issue, but know no reason for the behavior - it appears to be a bug of some sort. (Using Word 2010 BTW) Note that for me deleting the ActiveX control does *NOT* restore to the previous behavior! Could you use a MacroButton field instead of an ActiveX control?

Comment: Hi Cindy, thank you for looking into this. Unfortunately the department I'm creating the file for wants the Active X controls. Since the bug moves a few spaces ahead of the intended field, I'll be forced to code the macro to select a few fields prior to the intended one. This way, in conjunction with the odd behavior, I'll end up selecting the correct field.

Comment: Agreed, just thought I'd present an alternative to having to do that as it makes the code less self-documenting. Be sure to comment it! If the bookmarks are named as in the repro steps it wouldn't be a big deal since the pattern in consistent.

Comment: I'll update the thread with the final.  Thanks again Cindy, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the odd behavior was not found.

As a workaround I simply selected a Bookmark prior to the intended as shown in the code below.

Everything works as expected with Command Buttons.

```
Sub UpdateOptions()
Dim bProtected As Boolean
'Unprotect the file
If ActiveDocument.ProtectionType <> wdNoProtection Then
    bProtected = True
    ActiveDocument.Unprotect Password:=""
End If

Select Case ActiveDocument.FormFields("Bookmark0").Result
    Case "Bookmark1"
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Bookmark0").Select
        SendKeys "%{down}"  'Displays choices in drop-down field
    Case "Bookmark2"
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Bookmark1").Select
        SendKeys "%{down}"  'Displays choices in drop-down field
    Case "Bookmark3"
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Bookmark2").Select
        SendKeys "%{down}"  'Displays choices in drop-down field
End Select
If bProtected = True Then
    ActiveDocument.Protect _
        Type:=wdAllowOnlyFormFields, _
        NoReset:=True, _
        Password:=""
End If
End Sub
```

Thanks you all that entertained this thread.

Raudel